# How to install & uninstall wcf service using batch file

Tags: wcf, batch-file

i want to create two batch file one will deploy wcf service in IIS and also create virtual director and run it as a result any client can consume it. there will be another service which will stop the service and also remove the virtual directory.

### i search google and found some script but no working

the below script will create virtual director and run the site

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/servicemodelsamples /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\servicemodelsamples
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/servicemodelsamples" /enabledProtocols:http,net.tcp
pause
```

the below script will stop the site & remove virtual director

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/servicemodelsamples" /enabledProtocols:http
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe delete app /app.name:"Default Web Site/servicemodelsamples"
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" --bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']
```

i never use batch file but i like the batch file approach. so anyone tell the above script is ok or not because when i am running the first one then i am getting error : **do not have permission to read the config file**

here is my screen shot of batch file window with error
[image]
if possible give me any easy script for deploy wcf service to iis. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to read a config file, try opening the file as Administrator (I'm assuming you're on windows because it is a batch file.), and it will give the batch file Administrative access. (Beware if you downloaded this off the interwebs)

And, as a friendly reminder, please try to use good grammar and spelling.

Thanks,
Javaboy